# Get return value of function in execute script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have an extension to move from manifest v2 to v3. On manifest v3 executeScript has changed. Simply, in V2 I had a code like;

```
chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
        }, function (selection) {
            console.log(selection[0]);
            // I use the user selection for another purpose but for simplicity lets just log the selection
        });
    });
```

Now I have changed it to;

```
chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function (tabs) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            function: () => window.getSelection().toString(),
            target: {tabId: tabs[0].id}
        }, function (selection) {
            console.log(selection[0]);
            // For simplicity just log
        });
    });
```

But I can not read the selection. It is always undefined. How can I do that?

Comment: The main result can be accessed via `selection[0].result`. If the site has iframes then it's a different story for which there is a complicated solution. Also note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: yeah one the problem is about `selection[0].result` and the other one is about host permissions. I am trying to give access to all urls. If I do that, I will be able access the data.  Thanks for your comment